# Netbeans (OS X) hangs each time when changing arguments

Tags: java, netbeans

Each time I change project command line arguments within Netbeans, it hangs the moment I click 'Ok'. I have the newest updated version of Netbeans (on newest OS X) and the newest version of Java. The problem occurs within a project with two custom built packages.

An answer to this question should at least give an plausible explanation why this problem occurs. I'm anxious if any other people experience this exact same problem.

This exact problem isn't mentioned yet in these lists:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=hang
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=freeze

By using StackOverflow I'm hoping to get a quick response.

Comment: I'm assuming this doesn't occur in a project without those two packages? Or with only one of them?

Comment: I imported a project with one package to test this. Still hanged..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the newest Java JDK8 seems to solve all the problems I had with Netbeans on my Macbook.